# Show that $lim \frac{n^{2}}{n!} =0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Please check my proof and point mistake

Consider

$$\frac{n^{2}}{n!} = \frac{n}{(n-1)!}$$

$$\frac{n}{(n-1)!} <  \frac{n}{(n-2)!}$$

Then

$$ \frac{n}{(n-2)!} <\epsilon for every n>N$$

$$ \frac{1}{\epsilon }< \frac{(n-2)!}{n} for every n>N$$

We choose $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon }$

Therefore

$$ \frac{(n-2)!}{n}>\frac{(N-2)!}{N}>\frac{n^{2}}{n!}>\frac{1}{\epsilon } $$

therefore limit converge to 0

Comment: What is the idea behind the bound $\frac{n}{(n-1)!} <  \frac{n}{(n-2)!}?$

Comment: Transitivity property of inequality

Comment: What is the advantage of working with $\frac{n}{(n-2)!}$ instead of $\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$?

Comment: $\frac{n}{(n-2)!)}> \frac{1}{\epsilon }$ the inequality will hold automatically for $\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$.And I don't know how to deal with it directly because I just read a book  few page I know liitle how to solve it

Comment: What? Do you mean $\frac{n}{(n-1)!}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ automatically?

Comment: yes ,but I might  wrong . I never proof any inequality successfully without flaw before read Real Analysis book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have that $$\frac{n^{2}}{n!} = \frac{n}{(n-1)!}.$$ Now, note that

$$\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{1}{(n-2)!}\le \frac{2}{n-2}, \forall n\ge 2.$$

So, given $\epsilon>0$ we need to find $N$ such that $$n\ge N\implies \frac{2}{n-2}<\epsilon.$$ Well, $$\frac{2}{n-2}<\epsilon\iff n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}+2.$$

So, we have that

$$\forall\epsilon>0 \exists N \left(\ge \frac{2}{\epsilon}+2\right): n\ge N\implies 0<\frac{n^2}{n!}\le \frac{2}{n-2}<\epsilon.$$ This shows that the limit is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for correct proof ^ ^